# Rails - Unknown Attribute - Unable to add a new field to a form on create/update

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I am new to Rails.

Here is my controller/projects_controller.rb code

```
def create
@project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)
#@project.website = params[:website]
respond_to do |format|
  if @project.save
    Member.create!(
                   user_id: current_user.id,
                   project_id: @project.id,
                   project_manager: true,
                   status: "ready")

    format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def update
#@project.website = params[:website]
respond_to do |format|
  # if (@project.active_was == true) &&
  #   disabled = true
  # end

  if @project.update(project_params)
    # if disabled && (@project.active == false)
    #   flash[:modal] = true
    # end
    @project.website = params[:website]
    format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

  def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(
                                  :university_id,
                                  :project_name,
                                  :location,
                                  :tagline,
                                  :photos,
                                  :industry,
                                  :category,
                                  :description,
                                  :category_id,
                                  :expertise_string,
                                  :website,
                                  :active,
                                  :slug,
                                  :project_groups_attributes => [:id, :active, :university_id, :user_group_id]
  )
    end
```

Here is the code for my model/project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :members
    has_one :survey
    has_many :project_groups, foreign_key: "project_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :groups, :through => :project_groups, :source => :university
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_groups, :allow_destroy => true
    has_many :project_expertises, foreign_key: "project_id",
                            dependent: :destroy
    has_many :expertises, :through => :project_expertises, :source => :expertise
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :website
```

Here is my db/migrate/[timestamp]_create_projects.rb code

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.integer :university_id
      t.string :project_name
      t.string :tagline
      t.string :photos
      t.string :industry
      t.integer :category
      t.text :description
      t.text :website

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Why can I not add the 'website' field to this? Is there something more that I have to do?

Comment: Please be more specific about what exactly is not working and what you already tried.

Comment: @iltempo, I have an an existing model and controller logic in place. I am trying to include another field into the form as an input and displayed later onto another view so --> a new column into the 'projects' table. But I am unable to update the code to do so. Please let me know if you'd like me to explain anything else.

Comment: What you want there as `website` field? Website is any model in your system? as I can see you have made association with website so please be more specific. what you want as website field in your project form.

Comment: @GaganGami I want an input field on my form where the user can enter the url of a website which then takes the input and saves it to the database. Let me know if you'd like me to explain anything further. It is no model (yet) in my system. I feel that terminology wise, I am trying to include 'website' as a param.

Comment: @coderMint : So you haven't any model with name of `website` right? I have written the answer for you as guessing you have a model with the name of `website` but now I have to change my answer once you confirm

Comment: @GaganGami, no website model. I don't think I would need a website model as it would just be a part of another model, the 'project' model.

Comment: When adding additional information, please click on the "edit" link and add it to the question itself.  The comments are ephemeral and may be deleted, so the question should stand on its own.

Comment: I shall keep that in mind and edit my question asap @WayneConrad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment there is not any `Website` model available so there is not any meaning of putting association:

Simply remove this line from your `project` model

```
belongs_to :website
```

Comment: it gives me an 'unknown attribute: website' error now. Do you think this might be a database issue?

Comment: I ran 'bundle exec rake db:migrate' and it did not do anything. Then I ran 'bundle exec rake db:rollback', it just rolled back the migrate command from before.

Comment: Which I feel @GaganGami, shows that a migration is not happening for the 'website' parameter that I am trying to add.

Comment: I had to add a Website model and then run the "rake db:migrate" command. Thank you @Gagan Gami

Answer (score 0):

In `Project` model you've specified relation `belongs_to :website`. In migration schema instead of:

```
t.text :website
```

must be something like that:

```
t.references :website, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

When you generate model instead of
`rails g ... website:text` use `rails g ... website:references`.

ActiveRecord can't find foreign key to associate Project with Website.